# How would I automate command line software that only takes processes one image at a time?

Tags: command-line, images, automation

So, I have about a few thousand pixel-art pngs from a pixel-art game which I want to upscale. I've found out my software [(2dimagefilter)](https://code.google.com/archive/p/2dimagefilter/wikis/ImageResizer.wiki) but the software only takes one image in both the GUI and CLI version.

How would I go about automating?
SYNTAX is:

```
imgresizer.exe /load [IMAGE.png] /resize auto "LQ 4x" /save [OUTIMAGE].png
```

Comment: I'd use another app which can do that as a batch job, such as IrfanView, which operates well on Windows and Ubuntu OS's, and probably on others. It has a GUI which makes file selection easy.

Comment: I would but sadly Irfan View doesn't have xBR or hq / lq4x upscaling algorithms in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The software only takes one image in both the GUI and CLI version.

According to the command line help option for ImageResizer v129 (`imgresizer.exe -h`), you can specify multiple files to process at the command line:

> You can load and process multiple files at once by loading after saving again.

*ex. ImageResizer example code*

```
imageresizer.exe /load 1.bmp /resize 10x10 Pixel /save 1.jpg /load 2.bmp /resize 10x10 Pixel /save 2.jpg
```

---

*At a cursory glance, this option appears to be available in the standalone versions of ImageResizer since `ImageResizer-r17.exe`.*

---

Also, from ImageResizer v121 (`ImageResizer-r121.exe`) onward, "scripts" appear to be supported e.g.:

*ex. example_script.txt*

```
/load 1.png /resize auto "LQ 4x" /save 1.png
/load 2.png /resize auto "LQ 4x" /save 2.png
```

*ex. ImageResizer command*

```
imgresizer.exe /script example_script.txt
```

So using this option could allow multiple files to be processed at once as well.

---

*As with regular invalid commands, ImageResizer seems to print its "help" information if it cannot process the given script.*

---

> How would I go about automating [this]?

**General Approaches**

Since at least some versions of ImageResizer can apparently take batch instructions ("scripts", above), your basic choices would be to either:

- Create a script to directly call `imageresizer.exe` repeatedly for each file.
- Create a script (or use other methods) to make text files for ImageResizer to consume in order to process your desired images.

**Simple Examples**

1. In the folder containing your files, create a text file containing only file and folder names with ex.:

   ```
    dir /b > filenames.txt
   ```
2. Remove any folder names from e.g. `filenames.txt`. Repeat for any file names you do not wish to process, then save.

---

*Option 3A - Traditional Script*

Batch [FOR loops](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) can be used to repeatedly call an executable. Create a text file with a batch extension (`.bat`) and content similar to the following:

*ex. resizer.bat*

```
FOR /F %%G IN (filenames.txt) DO (
    imageresizer.exe /load %%G /resize auto "LQ 4x" /save %%G
)
```

Place e.g. `filenames.txt` and this batch file in the same directory as the files you wish to process. Then run ex. `resizer.bat` from the command line or just by double clicking it. In this case, `%%G` is the line read from ex. `filenames.txt`.

---

*Option 3B - ImageResizer "Script"*

Open e.g. `filenames.txt` in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/), then use [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) to replace the simple file names with your desired command(s):

- Open the Notepad++ *Replace* dialog with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.
- Make certain that the `Wrap around` and `Regular expression` options are marked.
- In the `Find what:` field, in parentheses, put `.*` then the file extension you wish to affect ex. `.png`:

  ```
  (.*.png)
  ```
- In the `Replace with` field, put your ImageResizer command but with `$1` in place of the file names ex.:

  ```
  /load $1 /resize auto "LQ 4x" /save $1
  ```

  `%1` is replaced by the matches found with ex. `(.*.png)`.
- Select `Replace all`.

  *ex. Notepad++ - Replace dialog*

  [image]
- This should turn all your file names into ex.:

  ```
  /load file1.png /resize auto "LQ 4x" /save file1.png
  /load file2.png /resize auto "LQ 4x" /save file2.png
  ```
- Save your new text file (e.g. as `example_script.txt`), then use `imageresizer.exe` to run the script ex.:

  ```
  imgresizer.exe /script example_script.txt
  ```

**Python**

An example of calling `imgresizer.exe /load [IMAGE.png] /resize auto "LQ 4x" /save [OUTIMAGE].png` for each `.png` image in the current directory and all sub-directories via [Python 3 on Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/):

```
# An example of how to use os.walk() and subprocess.run() to find desired files
# and feed them to ImageResizer.

import os
import os.path
import subprocess


# --- Variables, Etc. ---

# Directory where our files are stored. '.' is the current directory (whichever
# directory this script appears in). However, this can be any starting folder.
ROOT_DIR = '.'

# What type of files are we looking for?
# PREFIX = 'image_'
EXT = '.png'

# A list to hold our file path information.
full_paths = []


# --- Functions ---

# A small, custom function to build our ImageResizer command.
def build_command(filepath):

    # This string is directly invoked at the command line. Watch for spacing.
    # "\" breaks our long command into two separate lines.
    cmd_str = 'imageresizer /load ' + filepath + \
              ' /resize auto "LQ 4x" /save ' + filepath + '.jpg'

    return cmd_str


# ----- Main -----

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(ROOT_DIR):

    # Track the full path to our individual files.
    for name in filenames:

        # if name.startswith(PREFIX) and name.endswith(EXT):
        if name.endswith(EXT):

            # Test code
            # print(name)

            full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, name)
            full_paths.append(full_path)

# -----

# Visual aid
print('')

for path_item in full_paths:

    # Test code
    # print(path_item)

    # Put our file paths in quotes so we don't get errors when processing
    # sub-directories with spaces in their names.
    path_item = '"' + path_item + '"'

    try:

        # Custom function -> build_command()
        cmd = build_command(path_item)

        # Test code
        # print(cmd)

        subprocess.run(cmd, check=True)

    # Catch/print errors produced when calling ImageResizer with subprocess.
    except (OSError, subprocess.CalledProcessError) as err:

        # pass

        print('')
        print(err)
```

**Python Script Notes**

- `os.walk()` reads file/directory information and `subprocess.run()` is used to call external, non-Python commands, etc. i.e `imageresizer.exe`.
- If using a full path for `ROOT_DIR`, use `\\` rather than just`\` for path separators ex.:

  ```
  ROOT_DIR = 'C:\\Example\\Path'
  ```
- `os.walk(ROOT_DIR)` yields three items for each directory in a tree:

  - `dirpath` is the path to the current (sub-)directory.
  - `dirnames` is a list of the names of the subdirectories in `dirpath` (excluding `.` and `..`).
  - `filenames` is a list of the names of the non-directory files in `dirpath`.
- Names in the `dirnames` and `filenames` lists above are "bare" i.e. they do not contain any path components.
- `OSError` catches errors produced by the OS i.e. with files etc. and `subprocess.CalledProcessError` lets us know if there was an issue with the process called by `subprocess.run()` (i.e. it returned a non-zero value).

---

**Python Import References**

*[os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)*

*[os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)*

*[subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)*

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct, however I want to add my two cents.

The process you want can be done with PowerShell, if you don't know how to open it, you can use:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>>>type `powershell`>><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then you can use these codes to recursively process all images:

```powershell
$files=(Get-ChildItem -path "path\to\folder" -force -recurse -filter "*.png").fullname | %{if ($_ -match "\s") {'"'+$_+'"'}}
foreach ($file in $files) {Invoke-Command $("imgresizer.exe /load {0} /resize auto "LQ 4x" /save {0}" -f $file)}
```

Just replace "path\to\folder" with the actual path.

P.S. The above command will only work if 1, the full path of the executable `imageresizer.exe` is supplied; 2, you changed directory to the path where the executable is located; And finally, 3, you don't need to `cd` to the path of the `.exe` or use its full path if you have added its path to the [Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable.

Comment: Now this is definitely a smaller footprint than the accepted answer!